# Error extract keyword from Google search in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a sample code:

```
function getKeyword() {
    var instance = this;
    var googlePattern = /(www\.google\..*)/;

    this.params = function(parameters) {
        var result = [];
        var params = parameters.split("&");
        for(var p in params) {
            var kv = params[p].split("=");
            result[kv[0]] = kv[1];
        }
        return result;
    };

    this.googleKeywords = function(params){
        var query = params["q"];
        var pattern = /"(.*?)"|(\w+)/g;
        return decodeURIComponent(query).replace(/\+/g, " ").match(pattern);
    };

    this.parseReferrer = function(){
        var result = [];
        var pathAndParams = document.referrer.split("?");
        if(pathAndParams.length == 2) {
            var path = pathAndParams[0];
            var params = this.params(pathAndParams[1]);
            if(path.search(googlePattern) > 0) {
                result = this.googleKeywords(params);
            }
        }
        return result;   
    };

    return this.parseReferrer();
}
```

And then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.referrer && document.referrer != "") {
        if (document.referrer.search(/google\.*/i) != -1){
            var keyword = getKeyword();
            alert(keyword);
        } else {
            alert('Not search from google');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Not referrer');
    }
    </script>
```

Ex: when i search with keyword is "iphone 5", result not show alert("iphone 5") ? How to fix it ?

Comment: That's some nice looking code. What does it do and what's the problem?

Comment: @Niklas: I am forget set my question, i'm sorry !!!

Comment: What result does it return, if any? have you tried using `console.log` to check the return value of each function, to see where it's going wrong?

Comment: Did you already step through the script in the JavaScript debugger of your browser? Stepping through it should allow you to quickly see where your logic is failing.

Comment: Can you show a sample value for `document.referrer`. In a few quick tests I ran it does not contain a value for the `q` parameter anymore, which your code assumes. A quick search for this parameter turns up some hits that seem quite relevant to your case: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+referrer+url+q+parameter

Comment: @All: I have test with console.log(keyword) => result error in params[p].split("=") in line 10 with error is TypeError: params[p].split is not a function

Comment: Good catch @ha1tru0n9. Add a `if (params.hasOwnProperty(p))` to that line to filter out inherited properties.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: You think it is run good ?

Comment: I just tested with a `hasOwnProperty` check (do a search for that term if you don't know what it does yet) and then it gives me the correct keyword (on non-secure searches). `getKeyword() -> 
["iphone5"]`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I change params[p].split("="); to params.hasOwnProperty(p).split("="); getKeyword() -> ["undefined"] ?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `for in` construct loops over more than just the entries in the array. If you want to use `for in` you need to make sure that you're only processing the actual parameters. This is easiest accomplished by checking for `hasOwnProperty`:

```
this.params = function(parameters) {
  var result = [];
  var params = parameters.split("&");
  for(var p in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(p))
    {
      var kv = params[p].split("=");
      result[kv[0]] = kv[1];
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

Alternatively you can use a regular `for` loop over the array:

```
this.params = function(parameters) {
  var result = [];
  var params = parameters.split("&");
  for(var i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var kv = params[i].split("=");
    result[kv[0]] = kv[1];
  }
  return result;
};
```

Comment: I have test on my site with keyword ex: iphone 5 => result when console.log(keyword) is ...&q=&... => q = null, It's show 'iphone 5'

Comment: i has read this link: http://bowdeni.com/how-google-blocks-the-keyword-in-the-referrer/471/ => I think Google blocks the keyword in the referrer

Comment: That was my initial answer: Google does not pass the search term in the `q` parameter when the user did a secure search (so from HTTPS). But your code also was iterating over the `split` results in the wrong way.